# Custom metric function in Keras with tensorflow metric not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics

I am trying to implement a custom metric function in Keras to find precision at k as follows:

```
def PAt20(y_true, y_pred):
    score, up_opt = tf.metrics.precision_at_k(y_true, y_pred, 20)
    K.get_session().run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    with tf.control_dependencies([up_opt]):
       score = tf.identity(score)
    return score
```

where K is keras.backend, but it is not working at all, when the function is called during the compilation of the model I get the error:

> input must have last dimension >= k = 20 but is 1 for 'metrics_7/PAt20/precision_at_20/TopKV2' (op: 'TopKV2') with input shapes: [?,1], [] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <20>.

any suggestions?

Comment: Seems your model outputs only one class output, so it makes no sense to compute any top-k metric with k=20, you would need at least 20 output classes for that.

Comment: I thought the metric is called for the whole patch, so if I have one class output, then the shape of input is equal to my batch size, what thing do I miss here?

Comment: Top K refers to classes, not applied to the batch dimension.